# Matlab Function Formula Help- Sure to be simple

Tags: matlab, function, spreadsheet

I am very much a novice so you will need to speak novice to me. Thanks

Here is a function I am put together. Basic formula that I wanted to feed variables into from a spreadsheet, while spitting the results onto a new column.

```
function [ f ] = newgravity( m1,m2,r )

%NewtonsGravityFormula 

%   G=6.6738*10^-11 m^3*kg^-1*s^-1

g=6.6738*10^(-11);

f=g*m1.*m2./r.^2

end
```

And here is the command window. Note: variables1 is the name of the spreadsheet in the workspace window.

```
m1=variables1(:,1);

m2=variables1(:,2);

r=variables1(:,3);

newgravity(m1,m2,r)=variables1(:,4)
```

PROBLEM: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Bob said, I think you have got this the wrong way round. You probably want:

```
variables1(:,4) = newgravity(m1,m2,r);
```

i.e. store the output of the function in the 4th column of `variables1`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the first part of the post, you're defining a *function* `newgravity`.  But in the second part of the post, you're creating some values and then saying that `newgravity(some arguments) = something`  That second half is trying to create a new *variable* called `newgravity`, but that fails because m1, m2, or r aren't "real positive integers or logicals."

I think that you need to figure out what you're actually trying to do, and how to go about solving the problem.  Is `newgravity` a function (you pass in parameters, it returns a value), or is it a matrix of numbers that you're creating from the spreadsheet?